# How to connect my Pre-signed URL bucket in s3 to cloud-front

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-cloudfront

I am having a pre-signed URL in s3 bucket,and I connected to cloud front in distribution but when I am browsing the URL it is showing the following error:

```
`<Error> 
<Code>AccessDenied</Code> 
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
 <Expires>2019-04-01T15:53:17Z</Expires> 
<ServerTime>2019-04-01T16:49:14Z</ServerTime> <RequestId>8DCA892090B33291</RequestId>
<HostId> 82J0WSeDVrCLyOtCfcouBFlTvJfmvEqRUM4y1LCBzE= </HostId> 
</Error>`
```

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that the request has expired. How are you creating the pre-signed URL? The default timeout of a presigned URL for S3 is 3600 seconds (one hour).

Either you are setting it much less than that, or your hour is up and you'd need to generate a new presigned URL.

Comment: I updated the URL for 5 minutes but I am getting the same error when accessing pre-signed URL through cloud front

Answer (score 1):

The error "Request has expired" is returned by Amazon S3 when you try to access the presigned URL past the specified expiration date/time of the URL.

In this case, the owner of the object must generate a new presigned URL with a new expiration date.

Please follow this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/request-has-expired-s3-object/) for more information about this error.

Comment: Is there any way to access my pre-signed URL through the cloud front ?

Comment: When you try to access the signed URL, you need to have a separate CloudFront key pair and the key pair must be active. You cannot substitute an Amazon EC2 key pair for a CloudFront key pair.

For creating the CloudFront Keypair, please refer the link below :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html#private-content-creating-cloudfront-key-pairs